# Python import fails when called from PHP Page

Tags: php, python

When I am running my code from the terminal I am getting the output.
But when I am running the same from my php page using the following:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd($commandstring);
$output = shell_exec($command);
```

It gives no output..no error..nothing..

When I remove this import from my python code

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
```

then it shows an error in output

> name 'RandomForestClassifier' is not defined

then I used

```
import sys; print sys.path
```

to see the differences b/w running from PHP and from terminal

```
.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

this one is not there while running from the php.

Any permanent solution for this?

It will be better for me if I can fix it with the php code itself.

Well I am able to run other python code from php easily and they are showing the output. But this one has to import this line

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
```

Comment: Could you please add an example of the output ? and try to use the full path of your `$command` in `shell_exec` !

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add " 2>&1" at the end of $commandstring, so the stderr will be redirect to stdout and will be catched by shell_exec(). Maybe some error message will appear.

If this didn't solve your issue, try to run a simple "Hello world" python script from your PHP. You will know if the problem come from the PHP part or the  python part.

Comment: problem is from python part while importing the "from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier"

Comment: Can you launch your python script as www-data user ? If not, you can edit /etc/apache2/envvars as root to edit the "export PATH=" part, adding your missing folder here. Restart apache after. (if you're under apache)

Comment: "well currently /var/www has chmod 777 permissions" This shouldn't be related to our problem. About the test with www-data user, type "su www-data" then launch your python script.